# STM32 Disable and enable DMA and PWM controlled by timer

Tags: timer, stm32, dma, pwm, bluepill

I am using a STM32F103. I am trying to dynamically enable and disable a DMA transfer and a PWM signal, which are controlled by a timer. The timer is very unstable, and the result changes from reboot to reboot. The code runs the function CAM_startLineTransfer() which should enable the DMA transfer and PWM signal.

```
void CAM_startLineTransfer(CAM_HandleTypeDef *cam) {
    // init DMA
    while (cam->requestDataTimer->Instance->CNT <=  60) {}
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(cam->requestDataTimer, cam->requestDataChannel);
    HAL_TIM_OC_Start(cam->DMATimer, cam->DMAChannel);
    __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(cam->hdma, DMA_IT_HT);

    cam->status = RECEIVING;
}
```

When the DMA has transferred 640 bytes, an interrupt should be triggered.

```
void DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_tim2_ch3);
  CAM_stopLineTransfer(&hcam);
  transmitBuffer();
}
```

The function CAM_stopLineTransfer() should disable the DMA and the PWM signal, but NOT the timer itself. The timer should keep counting.

```
void CAM_stopLineTransfer(CAM_HandleTypeDef *cam) {
    // abort DMA
    HAL_TIM_OC_Stop(cam->DMATimer, cam->DMAChannel);
    while (cam->requestDataTimer->Instance->CNT <= 60) {}
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(cam->requestDataTimer, cam->requestDataChannel);

    cam->status = WAITING;
}
```

However, the timer is very unstable, and sometimes the entire timer is disabled, sometimes the interrupt is not called. What is happening? Here, the entire main program is.

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

#include "camera.h"

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_tim2_ch3;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
CAM_HandleTypeDef hcam;
uint8_t cameraData[640] = {10};
Picture pic1;

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void CAM_Handle_Init(CAM_HandleTypeDef *cam);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

int main(void)
{

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  CAM_Handle_Init(&hcam);
  CAM_init(&hcam);

  HAL_TIM_OC_Start_DMA(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3, &(GPIOA->IDR), hcam.pic->width);
  CAM_getReg(&hcam, 0x12);
  CAM_getReg(&hcam, 0x1E);
  CAM_getReg(&hcam, 0x13);
  CAM_getReg(&hcam, 0x3F);
  CAM_getReg(&hcam, 0x71);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      CAM_takePicture(&hcam);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

    CAM_update(&hcam);

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 6-1;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 120 -1;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM2;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 60;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_LOW;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TIMING;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_OC_MspInit(&htim2);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_MspInit(&htim2);
  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PC14 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_14;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB0 PB1 PB10 PB11
                           PB12 PB13 PB14 PB15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11
                          |GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB4 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

void CAM_Handle_Init(CAM_HandleTypeDef *cam) {
    cam->I2C_Address = 0x21;
    cam->destination = cameraData;
    cam->hdma = &hdma_tim2_ch3;
    cam->pic = &pic1;
    cam->requestDataTimer = &htim2;
    cam->requestDataChannel = TIM_CHANNEL_2;
    cam->DMATimer = &htim2;
    cam->DMAChannel = TIM_CHANNEL_3;
    cam->source = &(GPIOA->IDR);
    cam->status = STANDBY;
    cam->I2C_Handler = &hi2c1;

    cam->pic->x = 0;
    cam->pic->y = 0;
    cam->pic->height = 480;
    cam->pic->width = 640;

}

void transmitBuffer() {
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, cameraData, 640, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

/* USER CODE END 4 */
```

Answer (score 1):

I just saw that you used DMA_Channel instead of Timer_Channel:

`HAL_TIM_OC_Start(cam->DMATimer, cam->DMAChannel);`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).